# Why won't video play smoothly when saved on laptop Internal hard drive, but

Tags: windows-7, video

Why won't video play smoothly when saved on laptop Internal hard drive, but runs fine on external USB and external hard drives?

I've got a `Toshiba Satellite T130-13L` running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit with 4GB RAM and a Genuine Intel(R) CPU U4100 @ 1.30GHz 1.30GHz.

Graphics:
Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator Driver for Mobile

The problem I have is that videos I have downloaded from online and saved to either my C or D drive will not play smoothly on any media player I try (using latest versions of VLC and Windows Media Player, with most up to date codecs available), it will play for a few seconds, then stop, then play again. Almost as if I was buffering an online video.
Yet, when I copy the exact same file onto my Corsair 16GB USB stick, or my Western  Digital Elements 1TB external hard drive, the video plays fine.

Really stuck here, I have tried looking everywhere for help. Does anyone have any ideas as to what to do?

Comment: Sounds like there is contention for the disk, like it was paging while playing the file... But you have 4gb.  How much ram is free when you start playing?

Comment: In windows task manager, under performance it says 1.99Gb in use, physical memory in use is 50-52%

Comment: Does it hit max when you play video? Are these mkv files?

Comment: Slight jump up to 2.05gb in use. And nope they're avi files, standard definition.

Comment: Glad it got fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-Solved Edit-

**Solution:** Chckdsk /f.  Must have been some corruption?

*Also tried:*

- Setting VLC Media Player's "disable screensaver" option to off.
- Increasing the cache in VLC Media Player.
- Checking for OS-hardware compatibility issues.
- Checking for hardware-software compatibility issues.
- Scanning for heavy CPU usage via the task manager.
- Checking the event viewer for recurring errors.

Could you try turning off the "disable screensaver" option in VLC Media Player?  Because that's an issue that causes this problem with VLC Media Player.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't just comment.  Could you also tell us if this happens only in full-screen mode, or if it happens windowed?  Can you observe your task manager as you play the video back?  Press alt+ctrl+del and open task manager or open command prompt and type 'taskmgr' to open it.  Under the 'processes' tab, sort by 'CPU' usage.  See if anything is spiking.  It could be any number of things.

Comment: Unchecking Disable screensaver didn't work.
It's the CPU option I'm looking at under processes tab? vlc.exe spikes from 02 to as high as 12

Comment: Can you also say how long this problem has persisted and if it has been consistent?  There may be something temporary and software-related causing the issue.  And did you check what was eating up the CPU?  50% is a lot.  I'm on a P4, circa 2004, and I don't use 50% when I'm playing a HQ video.  I max out at 18%.

Comment: It's been going on for a few months now, and it's consistent accross every video type I have tried, on different media players.
50% was for the RAM, CPU never goes higher than 26%.

Comment: It's probably got a low spinrate because you're on a laptop, and if there's a lot going on, the hard drive itself could be the choke point.  It's also not hard to check a harddrive for corruption.  You might want to do that overnight, to be safe.  chkdsk /f.

Comment: 101 processes, CPU messages spikes from as low as 8% to as high as 30%.
Top in terms of memory - firefox - 290,948, vlc - 69,349, explorer - 42,376,dropbox 40,104, dwm (desktop window manager) - 20,932, toshibaservicestation - 18,632.

Comment: How do I check a hard drive for corruption?

Comment: Do you have NAS?  I've read on some forums that deleting the video files that you've put onto your internal hdd via a NAS and then copying them back onto your PC from your USB drive solves this issue.

Comment: You can run the command chkdsk /f from command prompt to check and make sure that your harddrive hasn't been corrupted.  If it has been corrupted, you should be careful about copying files onto your USB drive.  You should scan your USB drive and learn more about what to do with corrupted harddrives.

Comment: And no sorry I dont have NAS

Comment: Also, 8% is high if it's consistent.  30% is a high spike.  Because the pauses are intermittent, you should check and see if ending the processes resolves the issue.  Right click the process that is spiking and click 'end process tree'.  If it's explorer.exe, you can go to file>run>explorer.exe and start explorer, again.  You may also want to check your eventviewer.  File>run>eventvwr.  See if you're getting any consistent errors as you play videos.

Comment: Do you have any way to check your CPU heat and see if it's increasing dramatically when this happens?

Comment: In VLC, try going to Preferences>File and select "Show Settings (・)All".  Set the caching value to 1000ms.  Try increasing it to 20,000ms.  This should shift the burden to the RAM and eliminate the HDD as a choke point.  Please tell me if this works.  Back in a bit.

Comment: Ran the chkdsk /f and video seems to be playing fine now! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I tried everything but nothing happened. Finally i found that this is harddisk problem. Simply remove your laptop harddisk and replace another or with your friend laptop working harddisk. THis can solve your problem. simply check by replacing your harddisk......this is hard disk problem....sure

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).